# Is there a way to link to content within a post?

Tags: support, answers, hyperlinks

While the ability to link to footnotes would be helpful, being at the end of the post makes such notes relatively easy to find. (Returning to the place one was reading could still be a bit of a nuisance.)

However, for long answers, there may be cases where some content is not suitable for footnotes (e.g., it is properly inlined in later text or it has significant importance) but for which a simple statement like "(explained in detail later in this answer)" is somewhat less helpful.

Since good long answers are not common and the benefit would only apply to a subset of such answers, I suspect that this feature is not provided (and unlikely to be provided). (If such might be a worthwhile feature, perhaps it could be most easily supported by providing anchor names or ids for any header [somewhat like Wikipedia]. This would not provide a fully general and fine-grained internal linking mechanism, but it might be a good balancing of tradeoffs.)

Comment: Just to be clear,  you'd like to be able to inline (or 'one box') a specific subset of text from another post on the site?

Comment: @TimPost I was not thinking of inlining but rather linking. I gave the example of Wikipedia providing an html id to each header. I.e., it might be nice if at least headers were associated with an id (providing an id per paragraph [or list item??] might not be **completely insane**). This would presumably be an 'expert' feature, similar to using html tags rather than Markdown.

Comment: Is this more or less the same as the MSE feature request: [Support anchor names in posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts)?

Comment: @JonEricson The [highest voted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40356/226495) was basically what I was thinking of as a possible implementation. If it has not been implemented in over three and a half years, the prospect of it being implemented soon seems bleak. Sigh.

Comment: @Paul A. Clayton: Well, you never know. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Jon Ericson](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3306/jon-ericson) pointed out in [a comment](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/692#comment-2355) that [this feature has already been requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts). In fact, the highest voted answer proposed an implementation very similar to what is suggested above as a minimally intrusive option.

That feature request and the proposed implementation are over three and a half years old and the request has no official status indicated ([status-declined](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined), [status-deferred](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred), [status-planned](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned)). Perhaps a show of support (upvoting) of this feature request (and the proposed implementation) will encourage its implementation (or at least an official status decision).